# Can React Native produce UIButton instances in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I want to use React Native to create some buttons that are wired to trigger methods in a Swift app.  Is there a way to access TouchableHighlight instances from within a Swift UIViewController or ViewController class?

Comment: so if I understand once the button was tapped you want to present a new view controller right?

Comment: Just a custom callback, not necessarily navigation related. I just want to be able to write Swift functions that respond to touch events on buttons created via React Native.

Answer (score 0):

There are various options for buttons which you can find on npmjs.org. Below are a couple of options.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-button
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-icon-button

But you won't find a UIButton instance most likely since that is iOS specific. What you get is a touchable element which acts like a button. You can inspect the code of these modules on GitHub to see how they work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without installing additional Node modules by wrapping a `<Text>` component with a `<View>` component:

```
import React from 'react'    

class ExampleButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.pressButton = this.pressButton.bind(this);
    }
    pressButton() {
        console.log("The button was pressed!");
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text onPress={this.pressButton}>
                Button Text
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```